# How to get a specific or multiple values (or keys) from nested JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a (nested) data structure containing objects and arrays. How can I extract the information, i.e. access a specific or multiple values (or keys)?

```
  {
    "data": [{
      "name": "name1",
      "value": "value1",
      "list": [{
        "sname": "sname1",
        "svalue": "svalue1"
      }, {
        "sname": "sname2",
        "svalue": "svalue2"
      }]
    }]
  }
```

## jQuery

```
var pk = $("#pk").val();
console.log(pk);
url = "/register/search?id=" + pk;
console.log(url);
$('#largeTable').DataTable({
  "ajax": url,
  "bDestroy": true,
  "columns": [{
      "data": "name"
    },
    {
      "data": "value"
    },
    {
      "data": "list.1.sname"
    },
    {
      "data": "list.1.svalue"
    },
    {
      "data": null,
      "defaultContent": editview
    }
  ]
});
```

Here it is possible to display either first or second list values by using list.1 or list.0

But I want two values at a time.

Also, how could I access the `svalue` of the second item in `list`?

I tried with `data.list[1]` but:

> TypeError: data.list is undefined

Comment: `data[0].list[1]`, note `data` is also an array

Comment: `data.forEach((d)=>{ d.list.forEach( (l, i)=>{ console.log("list date: ", l, " index: ", i ;) } ) })`

Comment: ```data[0].list[1].svalue```

Comment: @Satpal and same problem i am getting

Comment: This question was [copy and pasted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42623722/how-to-set-nested-json-data-to-datatables) four hours later. I have voted to close the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Since `data` is an array, you should first get the item - and since you only have one item - you'd use `data[0]`, and then get access to the `list` property like `data[0].list[1]` - this will give you the second item in the `list` - but since you are interested in a specific property (`svalue`) of this item, you will then access it like this: `data[0].list[1].svalue`.

A better approach would be to loop through the items in the data array - and then for each item, loop through the items in the list array. See @Rajesh's comment.
I hope that helps;

Answer (score 0):

Specifically you can access it like this `object.data[0].list[1].svalue`. The reason `data.list` is `undefined` is because `data` corresponds to an array `data: [{ }]` this is why we use `data[0]`, but `data` itself is a key in an object so before you can get to `data` you need to access it. If the objects name where `data` resides were `object` *(like I did below)* then it'd be accessed like this `object.data[0]`

```js
const object = {
  "data": [{
    "name": "name1",
    "value": "value1",
    "list": [{
      "sname": "sname1",
      "svalue": "svalue1"
    }, {
      "sname": "sname2",
      "svalue": "svalue2"
    }]
  }]
}

console.log(object.data[0].list[1].svalue)
```

Comment: How to set multiple list values to datatables?